# Can you use Kendo UI's dataSource to get data straight from a database or C# dataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, kendo-ui

Based on my reading, it seems to me that the only way for Kendo UI's dataSource to get its data from remote devices is via HTTP. e.g.

```
var remoteDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
            url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json",
            dataType: "jsonp",
```

What if I do not have a way to get the data via HTTP?

I have a web forms page and I need to implement a treeView which will get data from a database.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It can bind to pretty much any source of json, so you have a lot of options.

In WebForms, a good one is WebMethods. You could add a WebMethod to your form and then bind the DataSource to it.

Or you could also create a web service, or build an aspx that renders json or xml instead of html (make sure you set the content-type!), or even call a static file that contains json.

I would start with reading this overview of the DataSource: http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/datasource/overview